# Partition table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We are designing a database for a multi tenant application that will be per tenant based. This tenant is potentially 1000 or more.

We have samples tables called:

orders

1. tenantid
2. orderid
3. name
4. date
5. totalamount

orderitems

1. tenantid
2. orderitemid
3. orderid
4. productid
5. quantity
6. price

We are thinking to do partition based on tenantid so it can ran faster query within the tenant.

CREATE TABLE orders (
  ...
) PARTITION BY HASH(tenantid) PARTITIONS ?;

Is that the best option to do this? How about the number of partition ... partition 1000?

I am appreciated your input.

Comment: [Please read the documentation for HASH partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-hash.html). Also, consider the benefits / drawbacks of having 1000 partitions. Would it really be the best thing to do (having your data spread over 1000 files)? (I don't know, I'm just asking)

Answer (score 0):

Rules of thumb:

- Don't use PARTITION on a table with less than a million rows.
- Don't have more than about 50 partitions.
- `PARTITION BY HASH` provides no performance benefit.

[More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).